# Phonegap - Android APP - how do i alter app launcher title

Tags: eclipse, cordova

Hopefully this should be a quick one to solve but - I'm building a HTMl5 Phonegap based App - all is going fine and it compiles and runs on the phone so far  - my issue is that the text under the launcher icon on the phone says 'test', i'd like this to say the name of my app - but cant figure out how to change it - can anyone help please!?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit res/values/strings.xml and change the value of app_name to whatever you want it to show up as.